# Propagating mouse events to underneath divs in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a button in a react page.
On top of the page, I have a transparent fixed div that is used in order to register mouse movements.

```
render() {
  return(
    <div>
      <div class="fixed-transparent"
         onMove={(e)=>{console.log('Mouse moved!')}}></div>
      <div class="btn"
         onClick={()=>{console.log('Button click!')}}>
         I'm a button
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem is that because the fixed div is on top of the page, the button does not respond to the mouse clicks.

**How do I propagate the mouse clicks from the fixed div to the ones underneath?**

Comment: Does `fixed-transparent` have higher `z-index` than `btn`? You need to make sure that button is on top, so it receives the click event.

Comment: But then mouse movement will not be detected when the mouse is over the button.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. You can have your child component (that's what "underneath components" are called) listen to the mouse events as well or if you have your "transparent" component pass the click event handler down to the child components. Something like this:

```
import react, { Component } from 'React';

export class ButtonComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { onClick } = this.props;
    return <button onClick={onClick}>Click Me!</button>
  }
}

export class TransParentComponent extends Component {
  onClick = e => {
    console.log('handle click here');
  }
  onMove = e => {
    console.log('Mouse moved!');
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <div class="fixed-transparent" onMouseMove={this.onMove}></div>
        <ButtonComponent onClick={this.onClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```